# how to rotate an image I obtain from a file with google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have code that creates a PNG from a slide in a Google presentation deck.  Before writing the PNG to a file, I'd like to rotate it by 90 degrees.  Any way to achieve the desired rotation?  Here's my code so far:

`// export the generated slide to an image`

`var exportUrl = "https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/" + presentationTmplId + "/export/png?id=" + presentationTmplId + "&pageid=" + newSlideId;`

`var parameters = {`

`method: 'GET',`

`headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },`

`contentType: 'application/json',`

`muteHttpExceptions: true,   };`

`var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, parameters);`

`var blob = response.getBlob();`

`// ??? how to rotate my blob here before saving ???`

`DriveApp.createFile(blob).setName('menu main left.png');`

I've looked for a way to convert the blob to an Image so that I can use the setRotation() method, but no luck.  Any possible way to achieve the overall goal of rotating a blob containing a PNG?

Comment: You might try to search for tanaike and image library he has some image handling functional on github I think.

Comment: I had a look and found tanaike's libraries on github, but unfortunately, no methods for rotating an image-as-blob. :-(

Comment: Yeah he would have probably answered you last evening if he had one.  So I don't know of any nor I am interested in writing one

Comment: 1)create a google slide, and insert the image (2) in google slide you can use setRotation to rotate the image (3) finally extract and save the image using getblob , follow the documentation https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/image , may help

Comment: I tried creating a slide, inserting the image, invoking setRotation, and extracting the blob, but the blob returned by image.getBlob has not been rotated.  And I can confirm visually that the setRotation call worked, so I'm assuming that setRotation doesn't affect the underlying blob, only how it's displayed on the slide. :-(

Answer (score 0):

While kl kl's suggestion to create an Image from a blob by first creating a dummy Slide as a temporary container for an Image did not initially pan out, it led to the final solution.  Since Image.setRotation does not rotate the underlying blob of image data, I resized the Image to the size of the Slide and then exported the Slide itself as a blob, resulting in the desired outcome.

Thanks to everyone who commented.  Your time and interest ultimately led to working piece of code that automates the generation of product menus in my retail store!